# What is the preferred way to complete this while loop for desired output?

Tags: java, while-loop, nested-if

I have written a little program that simply takes the name of an email sender by looking at the email address and returning the letters up to the `@` character.

I have written the while loop in two ways, one way primes the loop and the second uses a nested if statement. Are both as good as each other or is one a preferred method over the other?

Priming while loop:

```
public void FindUserName() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char symbol = ' ';
    System.out.println("Please enter email!");
    symbol = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);

    while (symbol != '@') {
        System.out.print(symbol);
        symbol = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Using nested if statement to break if `symbol == '@'`

```
public void FindUserName() {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char symbol = ' ';
    System.out.println("Please enter email!");

    while (symbol != '@') {
        symbol = keyboard.findWithinHorizon(".", 0).charAt(0);
        if (symbol == '@') {
            break;
        }
        System.out.print(symbol);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to make a loop, you can easily use :

```
String email = "email@abd.com";
String str = email.substring(0, email.indexOf("@"));
```

This will give your `email`

Comment: Still learning. Have not come across .substring until now, after you using it. Thank you as this seems to be much simpler but never the less, I am learning while loops and would still like to know the preferred way when using a while loop.

Comment: @James in your case you don't need to use break, you can use it in case you want to avoid an action after your if, in this case break make sense, but in your case you already have a check in your loop so no need to use break

Comment: I understand now that I was actually repeating myself using that If statement as i had already checked it in the while loop. This information is very valuable to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement in the *second loop* has no sense because *while's condition* already checks that.

Try to use regular expressions. Option 1

```
String[] splitted = email.split("@");
String name = splitted[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You say, the while condition already checked it and it has but even so, the System.out.print(symbol); will be initialized and the @ will be printed before the loop ends.

Comment: Yes. This is because you have an empty symbol in the beginning of you loop. You should initialise it before. Because you should avoid double check ing of one variable inside one loop. It is a bad practice and you violates Don't Repeat Yourself rule.

Comment: Ah ha. Now I understand. I didn't receive an error for initializing so i didn't. This makes a lot of sense now. Thank you.